# Symfony - One time message / upcoming maintenance

Tags: symfony, notifications, message

Just wondering what your thoughts are on the best way to achieve this?

My problem is I want to be able to add new update messages to the top of the website. Eg upcoming maintenance shedules, promoting new features etc. These will be on a random basis whenever I have new information to promote.

I want the message to stay on every page request until the user clicks the dismiss button and then never have it shown again.

My current thinking is either:
Store the messages in a database and then store in cache when user dismisses it so it won't show again. This seems like a waste of a database call though on every page request.

Store in an xml file and load on every request and then store a cookie if user has dismissed that message.

Is there a better way to achieve this or something built into Symfony that can handle this?

Thank you